# classList.remove is not removing the class of one of my elements

Tags: javascript, css

```js
const dropdowns = document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown");

// Loop through all dropdown elements

dropdowns.forEach((dropdown) => {
  const select = dropdown.querySelector(".select");
  const caret = dropdown.querySelector(".caret");
  const menu = dropdown.querySelector(".menu");
  const options = dropdown.querySelectorAll(".menu li");
  const selected = dropdown.querySelector(".selected");

  dropdown.addEventListener("click", () => {
    menu.classList.toggle("menu-open");

    options.forEach((option) => {
      option.addEventListener("click", () => {
        menu.classList.remove("menu-open");

        options.forEach((option) => {
          option.classList.remove("active");
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```css
/*Global settings*/

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

*,
::after,
::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/*-------------------------------------------------------------*/

body {
  font-family: "Roboto";
  background-color: #23242a;
  color: #fff;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.dropdown {
  margin: 4rem;
  position: relative;
}

.select {
  min-width: 15rem;
  border-radius: 0.7rem;
  background-color: #2a2f3b;
  padding: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.select:hover {
  background-color: #323741;
}

.caret {
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.menu {
  background-color: #323741;
  padding: 0.5rem 0.5rem;
  border-radius: 0.7rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4rem;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}

.menu li {
  border-radius: 0.2rem;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0.3rem 0.8rem;
  margin: 0.3rem;
}

.menu li:hover {
  background-color: #2a2d35;
}

.active {
  background-color: #23242a;
}


/*Clicked Styles (Added later in JS) */

.caret-rotate {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.menu-open {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.3.0/css/all.min.css" />

  <title>Drop-down</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <div class="select">
      <span class="selected">Figma</span>
      <div class="caret"><i class="fa-solid fa-caret-down"></i></div>
    </div>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li>Framer</li>
      <li>Sketch</li>
      <li>Invision Studio</li>
      <li class="active">Figma</li>
      <li>Adobe XD</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="dropdown">
    <div class="select">
      <span class="selected">Facebook</span>
      <div class="caret"><i class="fa-solid fa-caret-down"></i></div>
    </div>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li class="active">FaceBook</li>
      <li>instagram</li>
      <li>Twitter</li>
      <li>Linkedin</li>
      <li>Tik Tok</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="app.js"></script>

</html>
```

I have a div with the clase “menu” containing a list of options, I set the display to none. (1st image)
[1st image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkkSW.png)

When the user clicks it , The program adds the class “menu-open”, therefore making the menu visible. (2nd image)
[2nd image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkSID.png)

MY PROBLEM

-The idea is that the menu is closed right after the user selects one of the options, I was hoping to achieve that by removing the class “menu-open” after a click event, therefore getting the element back to its original display:none

Even though I was able to solve it by changing this from my JS:

FROM:

JS Line 12: `dropdown.addEventListener("click", () => {...`

To

JS Line 12 `select.addEventListener("click", () => {...`

I am unable to explain the behaviour of this, can someone explain what’s going on? I’d really appreciate it.

Comment: tell more information with some code snippets.

Comment: Why post a link to CodePen when you can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) here?

Answer (score 0):

The problems is that when you click on an option, the click bubbles out to the menu. So the option toggles the menu closed, but then the menu receives the click and toggles it open again.

Use `Event.stopPropagation()` in the click listener for the option to prevent this.

```js
const dropdowns = document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown");

// Loop through all dropdown elements

dropdowns.forEach((dropdown) => {
  const select = dropdown.querySelector(".select");
  const caret = dropdown.querySelector(".caret");
  const menu = dropdown.querySelector(".menu");
  const options = dropdown.querySelectorAll(".menu li");
  const selected = dropdown.querySelector(".selected");

  dropdown.addEventListener("click", () => {
    menu.classList.toggle("menu-open");

    options.forEach((option) => {
      option.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        e.stopPropagation();
        menu.classList.remove("menu-open");

        options.forEach((option) => {
          option.classList.remove("active");
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```css
/*Global settings*/

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

*,
::after,
::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/*-------------------------------------------------------------*/

body {
  font-family: "Roboto";
  background-color: #23242a;
  color: #fff;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.dropdown {
  margin: 4rem;
  position: relative;
}

.select {
  min-width: 15rem;
  border-radius: 0.7rem;
  background-color: #2a2f3b;
  padding: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.select:hover {
  background-color: #323741;
}

.caret {
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.menu {
  background-color: #323741;
  padding: 0.5rem 0.5rem;
  border-radius: 0.7rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4rem;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}

.menu li {
  border-radius: 0.2rem;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0.3rem 0.8rem;
  margin: 0.3rem;
}

.menu li:hover {
  background-color: #2a2d35;
}

.active {
  background-color: #23242a;
}


/*Clicked Styles (Added later in JS) */

.caret-rotate {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.menu-open {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.3.0/css/all.min.css" />

  <title>Drop-down</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <div class="select">
      <span class="selected">Figma</span>
      <div class="caret"><i class="fa-solid fa-caret-down"></i></div>
    </div>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li>Framer</li>
      <li>Sketch</li>
      <li>Invision Studio</li>
      <li class="active">Figma</li>
      <li>Adobe XD</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="dropdown">
    <div class="select">
      <span class="selected">Facebook</span>
      <div class="caret"><i class="fa-solid fa-caret-down"></i></div>
    </div>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li class="active">FaceBook</li>
      <li>instagram</li>
      <li>Twitter</li>
      <li>Linkedin</li>
      <li>Tik Tok</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="app.js"></script>

</html>
```